# Are questions regarding similar game suggestion on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I need to ask a question on the forum about similar games like Bang. Is this on-topic or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do not allow game recommendation questions. Please see the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages in the help center for more information about what questions we allow.

Answer (score -3):

Murgatroid99 was a bit blunt in his answer.  You can on ask for ways of finding similar games. Example: "How can I find games that are similar to another "XXXX"?

This would wield answers such as: "You can go to www.boardgamegeek.com and do a search by type of game" , etc.